# How Can I Reset The File Pointer to the Beginning of the File in Java?

Tags: java, filereader

I am writing a program in Java that requires me to compare the data in 2 files. I have to check each line from file 1 against each line of file 2 and if I find a match write them to a third file. After I read to the end of file 2, how do I reset the pointer to the beginning of the file?

```
public class FiFo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FileReader file1=new FileReader("d:\\testfiles\\FILE1.txt");
        FileReader file2=new FileReader("d:\\testfiles\\FILE2.txt");
        try{
            String s1,s2;
            while((s1=file1.data.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("s1: "+s1);
                while((s2=file2.data.readLine())!=null){
                    System.out.println("s2: "+s2);
                }
            }
            file1.closeFile();
            file2.closeFile();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class FileReader {
    BufferedReader data;
    DataInputStream in;

    public FileReader(String fileName)
    {
        try{
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    public void closeFile()
    {
        try{
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok - I did the spelling and the grammar, I'm not doing the formatting.

Comment: I suspect the original poster may be mis-interpreting the assignment and what was actually asked for was a degenerate `diff`. This guess is based on prior questions by the OP and the comparative difficulty of the solutions.

Answer (score 15):

I believe [`RandomAccessFile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) is what you need. It contains: `RandomAccessFile#seek` and `RandomAccessFile#getFilePointer`.

`rewind()` is `seek(0)`

Answer (score 5):

I think the best thing to do would be to put each line from file 1 into a `HashMap`; then you could check each line of file 2 for membership in your `HashMap` rather than reading through the entire file once for each line of file 1.

But to answer your question of how to go back to the beginning of the file, the easiest thing to do is to open another `InputStream`/`Reader`.

Comment: +1 - it is much more efficient to load file 1 first. Unless the files can be very large.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you could just close and reopen the file like this:

```
     while((s1=file1.data.readLine())!=null){
         System.out.println("s1: "+s1);
         FileReader file2=new FileReader("d:\\testfiles\\FILE2.txt");
         while((s2=file2.data.readLine())!=null){
             System.out.println("s2: "+s2);
             //compare s1 and s2;
         }
         file2.closeFile()
     }
```

But you really don't want to do it that way, since this algorithm's running time is O(n<sup>2</sup>). if there were 1000 lines in file A, and 10000 lines in file B, your inner loop would run 1,000,000 times.

What you should do is read each line and store it in a collection that allows quick checks to see if an item is already contained(probably a HashSet).

If you only need to check to see that every line in file 2 is in file 1, then you just add each line in file one to a HashSet, and then check to see that every line in file 2 is in that set.

If you need to do a cross comparison where you find every string that's in one but not the other, then you'll need two hash sets, one for each file. (Although there's a trick you could do to use just one)

If the files are so large that you don't have enough memory, then your original n<sup>2</sup> method would never have worked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

well, Gennady S. answer is what I would use to solve your problem.

> I am writing a program in Java that requires me to compare the data in 2 files

however, I would rather not code this up again.. I would rather use something like http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/

Comment: That's great to know that there is an open source that tackles these kind of problems, though GPL license type may become a serious issue in using it.

Comment: @Gennady - only in the land of dinosaurs :-).  But seriously, if you are unhappy with the GPL, you are free to develop your own non-GPL libraries.

Comment: @Stephen C, it's not me, it's company's law department :-) But anyhow GPL requires your code to to become GPL which is not appropriate in many cases.

Comment: @Gennady - and my response remains the same.  If GPL is not suitable for you/your company, don't complain about it.  Just find a non-GPL alternative or develop one in-house.

Comment: @Stephen C, that wasn't complain. That was the information that important to decide whether the library is usable for the person asking question.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you should consider other approaches to the problem. For the specific question of returning to a previous point in a file, [`java.io.FileReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) would appear to inherit [`mark()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#mark%28int%29) and [`reset()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#reset%28%29) methods that address this goal. Unfortunately, `markSupported()` returns `false`.

Alternatively, [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)  *does* support `mark()`. The program below prints `true`, illustrating the effect.

```
package cli;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileReaderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("src/cli/FileReaderTest.java")));
            in.mark(1);
            int i1 = in.read(); in.read(); in.read();
            in.reset();
            int i2 = in.read();
            System.out.println(i1 == i2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, there are better algorithms - investigate these

aside:

FileReader doesn't implement mark and reset, so trashgod's comments are inaccurate.
You'd either have to implement a version of this (using RandomAccessFile or what not) or wrap in a BufferedReader. However, the latter will load the whole thing in memory if you mark it

Comment: Update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227197/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick Question. can't you keep one object pointed at the start of the file and traverse through the file with another object? Then when you get to the end just point it to the object at the beginning of the file(stream). I believe C++ has such mechanisms with file I/O ( or is it stream I/O)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could just re-initialize the file 2 file reader and that should reset it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can clearly indentify the **dimension** of your file you can use *mark(int readAheadLimit)* and *reset()* from the class *BufferedReader*.
The method *mark(int readAhedLimit)* add a marker to the current position of your BufferedReader and you can go back to the marker using *reset()*.

Using them you have to **be careful** to the number of characters to read until the *reset()*, you have to specify them as the argument of the function *mark(int readAhedLimit)*.

Assuming a limit of 100 characters your code should look like:

```
class MyFileReader {
    BufferedReader data;
    int maxNumberOfCharacters = 100;

    public MyFileReader(String fileName)
    {
        try{
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            data = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            //mark the current position, in this case the beginning of the file
            data.mark(maxNumberOfCharacters);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resetFile(){
        data.reset();
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        try{
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reset the file pointer to the top of the file, reinitialize your buffer reader. I assume that you are also using the try and catch block to check for end of the file.

```
`//To read from a file. 
      BufferedReader read_data_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Datafile.dat"));'
```

Let's say this is how you have your buffer reader defined. Now, this is how you can check for end of file=null.

```
boolean has_data= true;

while(has_data)
     {    
      try
     {
     record = read_data_file.readLine();
     delimit = new StringTokenizer(record, ",");
     //Reading the input in STRING format. 
     cus_ID = delimit.nextToken();
     cus_name = delimit.nextToken();'
      //And keep grabbing the data and save it in appropriate fields. 
     }
catch (NullPointerException e)
     {
      System.out.println("\nEnd of Data File... Total "+ num_of_records 
                       + " records were printed. \n \n");
      has_data = false; //To exit the loop. 
      /*
        ------> This point is the trouble maker. Your file pointer is pointing at the end of the line. 
     -->If you want to again read all the data FROM THE TOP WITHOUT   RECOMPILING: 
      Do this--> Reset the buffer reader to the top of the file.
      */                      
      read_data_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("datafile.dat")));
}
```

By reinitializing the buffer reader you will reset the file reader mark/pointer to the top of the file and you won't have to recompile the file to set the file reader marker/pointer to beginning/top of the file. 
You need to reinitialize the buffer reader only if you don't want to recompile and pull off the same stunt in the same run. But if you wish to just run loop one time then you don't have to all this, by simply recompiling the file, the file reader marker will be set to the top/beginning of the file.