# Java : How do I set the FileReader obj (that is already pointing to some thing) to point to the first line of the file?

Tags: java, filereader

I am new to java. I just have a question. How do I set the FileReader obj
(that is already pointing to some thing) to point to the first line of the file ?

```
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            reader.read(buffer);
            System.out.println("Printing using temporary buffer");
            for ( i in value) { 
                System.out.print(buffer[i]);
            }

            BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = breader.readLine(); 
            System.out.println("From buffered reader");
            System.out.println(line);   
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
```

Here reader(FileReader obj) is already pointing to somewhere in the file. I may have to move the reader pointer to the starting line of the file.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you can call `reader.reset();` If you can't do that, you would probably have to close the reader and recreate it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Somehow control is passed to the Catch block and says File not Found

Comment: You should print the error message or stack trace instead of a hard-coded string.

Comment: This might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226699/how-can-i-reset-the-file-pointer-to-the-beginning-of-the-file-in-java. Please refer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Wrap it in a [`java.io.PushbackReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html), and push the temporarily read data back with the `unread()` method.
2. Wrap it in a [`java.io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and use the `mark()` and `reset()` methods.